# Is this limit rule correct?

Tags: calculus, limits

Is it true that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(a^2\right) = \lim_{x\to\infty}(a)\times \lim_{x\to\infty}(a)$$if $a=f(x)$?

Comment: Is the function $x\mapsto x^2$ continuous ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. More precisely put:

> If $\lim_{x\to\infty} a(x)$ exists, then the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}(a(x))^2$ also exists and the equality $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (a(x))^2= \left(\lim_{x\to\infty} a(x)\right)^2$$ is true.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that this was true, but wasn't sure. Ill check the answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: @SamLiemburg It's also good practice to try and prove the statement yourself.

Comment: But $\lim a^2$ may exist and $\lim a$ not, and then it is not true.

Answer (score 2):

This are the [basic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties) for limits provided that   $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_\limits{x \to \infty} g(x)$ exist.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) + g(x)) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)+ \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) \tag{1}$$ 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) - g(x)) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) -  \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) \tag{2}$$ 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) \cdot g(x)) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \cdot   \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) \tag{3}$$ 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{ g(x)} = \frac{\lim_\limits{x \to \infty} f(x) }{  \lim_\limits{x \to \infty} g(x)} \tag{4}$$

Equation $(4)$ holds if $g(x)\ne 0,\; \forall x>A(g)$, where $A(g)$ is an arbitrary   constant depending on $g$ but not on $x$. If you substitute in equation $(3)$  both $f$ and $g$ by $a$ you get
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(a(x)^2\right)=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(a(x)\cdot a(x)\right)=\lim_{x \to \infty}a(x)\cdot \lim_{x \to \infty}a(x)=\left(\lim_{x \to \infty}a(x)\right)^2 \tag{5}$$

Comment: Provided the limit, $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x), g(x)$ exists.

Comment: @A---B Thank you. Edited the post.